# How to apply custom style to LayoutAnchorable (AvalonDock)

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I have this code where the part where the style applied for ListBox works just fine, but the first part where I want to change the style of the LayoutAnchorable does not work at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="test"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

The `Property="Title"` is just there for an example. I actually want to remove docking combo button from the title.

Comment: Try making the target type LayoutAnchorableControl instead of LayoutAnchorable